# Substituir string_concat() por equivalente

Tags: python, django, deprecated

Eu sou iniciante em Python e aceitei participar de um projeto mais ou menos antigo, que estava usando Python 2.7 até o momento. No início do ano, esta versão foi depreciada e agora não consigo mais instalar nada com o pip, portanto preciso atualizar todo o projeto para o Python 3.x. O primeiro empecilho para isso são as funções `string_concat()`, que costumavam pertencer ao módulo `django.utils.translation` até o Django 1.9, sendo então descontinuadas. A seguir, um exemplo de código em que ela aparece:

```
'ESPESSURAF' : {
    u'NOME':u'ESPESSURAF',
    u'NOME_HTML': string_concat(NOMES_HTML['ESPESSURAF'], u' <em>t&nbsp;<sub> f</sub> </em> [m]'),
    u'UNIDADE':u' <em>t&nbsp;<sub> f</sub>[m] </em>',
    u'COMENTARIO':u'',
    u'TOOLTIP' : u''
},
```

Todas as outras ocorrências são bem semelhantes a esta, então a solução de uma deve valer a todas. Li em algum lugar que format_lazy() pode ser uma boa substituição, mas não tenho experiência suficiente para saber fazer esta adaptação. Preciso consertar isso o mais rápido possível, ficaria enormemente grato por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Você pode usar FString para concatenar as string, não?

Comment: Sim, mas estas são lazy strings; não sei direito como isso funciona, mas pelo que eu entendi, servem para possibilitar a tradução para outros idiomas. Então concatenar com f-strings nessa situação pode quebrar as traduções, acredito eu.

Comment: Cara, dá uma procurada na lib `ugettext_lazy`, talvez seja o que você precisa. Quando trabalhei com um projeto django era assim que a gente mantinha as traduções.

Comment: Sim, tinha achado algo que parecia ser o próprio código da função, mas não tive a oportunidade de testar, agora já é tarde demais.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o tópico de deprecação do `string_concat` no issue tracker do Django, todas as ocorrências de `string_concat` podem ser substituídas por `format_lazy('{}'*len(params), *params)`.

Exemplo de polyfill, caso não queria mudar o nome da função:

```py
def string_concat(params):
    return format_lazy('{}'*len(params), *params)
```

Referências:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27067
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#formatting-strings-format-lazy